# Owin disposes IdentityDbContext before initializing Controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I've just migrated my project to Owin and not so familiar with its architecture.
Before that I had a dbContext, which I had initialized in the Controller constructor.
After migrating to Owin, I inherited my have inherited my dbcontext from IdentityDbContext.

I removed its initialisation from the constructor and have created a controller property (I expect here that I could retrieve the context from the owin repository whithin the life of the current request and continue to use it in my project):

```
 public MyController()
{
 private static MyDataContext _myContext ;
    public MyDataContextMyContext
    {
        get
        {
            return _myContext ??
                   (_myContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<MyDataContext>());
        }
    }}}
```

Static field is required here, in MyDataContext I initialize it:

```
public class MyDataContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
    public static MyDataContext Create()
        {
            return new MyDataContext();
        } }
```

In the Startup.cs I have this:

```
 app.CreatePerOwinContext<MyDataContext>(MyDataContext.Create);
 app.CreatePerOwinContext<MyUserManager>(MyUserManager.Create);
 app.CreatePerOwinContext<MySignInManager>(MySignInManager.Create);
```

in my base controller I have this constructor:

```
    public MyController()
    {

        if (MyContext.Database.Exists())
        {/.../}
```

'If' line throws an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed
>   because the DbContext has been disposed.

Of course overriding dispose in dbcontext helps (just for test), but apparently this is wrong approach.

My initial goal is to use the same context per request while the request is alive. I do not want to create a new db context inside the controller (why should I if already one was created before?) Could you please suggest a best practice of using mvc5 authentication with the EF datacontext?

Comment: I suggest you to have one context per request, It's the only way to control whats really changed/added/deleted and saved in one transaction (when you call `dbContext.SaveChanges()` or `dbContext.Commit()`.

Comment: hi, but this is exactly what  I a trying to achieve, however, when I try to retrieve the context it is already disposed for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the static keyword... The controller class must be istantiated per request storing the context in a static variable share it between calls.

Comment: I'm talking about "private static MyDataContext _myContext ;" this is just a field in your controller, no way part of owin specification, the getter you use to access this field is made like that for testability, you can inject the context in tests...

Comment: thank you! my bad, I really don't know why I marked this private field as static. Thanks again.